Combining GoogleOpenId and Cookie authentication in ASP.NET Core 8
I have an application that the primary authentication is using cookies and the standard auth pattern. I want to also have GoogleOpenId auth so particular functions can access Google Calendar.
In program.cs I have
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    })
    .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
    });

Then in controllers I have something like this
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleAuth([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    // ...
}

and
[Authorize]
public Task<IActionResult> RegularAuth()
{
    var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
}

Now the problem is if I follow the flow

Log in with my normal username/password cookie authentication. All is fine
Then go to the GoogleAuth endpoint, it logs into Google and returns, all fine.

However, if I then go back to the RegularAuth endpoint, my User and Claims have been overwritten with the Google token. I basically need to have both of them, I am effectively double authed, depending on the endpoint.
How is that possible?
Edit:
What would be really best is if there was a way to implement the old style flow with GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow in .NET 8.

Sure it is possible. But this project will need 2 cookie schemes to do this. 
GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme actually needs a "cookie scheme" to generate a cookie after google login. By default, it will use the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme. So there's a conflict. Both your "cookie auth" and "google auth" are using the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme for keep login state. You could see they both generate a cookie with the same Name .AspNetCore.Cookies after login

So you just need to add another cookie scheme for "google auth" like following
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie("GoogleAuthCookieScheme", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyGoogleAuth";
    })
    .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "xxx";
        options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
        options.SignInScheme= "GoogleAuthCookieScheme";
    });


Thanks, this partially works. However if I then access the User with httpContext.User, it shows the most recent (Google) logged in user. I need to be able to access both users independently, and their associated claims.

@Craig HttpContext can only signin 1 user. I think you could try parse the 2 userpricipals first. When you need httpcontext to login another user you could await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("old cookiescheme") then await HttpContext.SigninAysnc("new principal" ,"new cookiescheme"). And this will not deal with the "openidSchme" so you will not be redirect to login again.

It sounds like they have really broken the Google Auth in ASP.NET Core, which is what everyone says.
